# Multiple fragments, setRetainInstance(true) and screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm switching between multiple fragments via replace. The fragments are also added to the back stack.

Now I want that on orientation change the fragments aren't created again. I put `setRetainInstance(true)` on each of them.

Fragment A behaves ok. Then I switch to fragment B, rotate the screen and see fragment A. What am I doing wrong? Or is this expected?

Comment: For some reason setRetainInstance(true) and addToBackStack() arent suppose to be in the same move.  Acording to the documentation "This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack. If set, the fragment lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is recreated"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling **setRetainInstance(true)** to fragment doesn't stop your activity from destroying and recreating itself. Probably you initialize the first fragment in your **onCreate** method, so it works with your first fragment as expected, but not with the second one. You either need to store which fragment is shown using **onSaveInstanceState** method in your activity and show the corresponding one in OnCreate, or you need to set your activity flags to **android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"** to keep it from destroyng on screen orientation change.

Comment: "You either need to store which fragment is shown using onSaveInstanceState method in your activity and show the corresponding one in OnCreate" -- that should automatically be handled by the `FragmentManager` AFAIK. What you have to do is not screw it up by running *another* transaction in `onCreate()`, such as one that displays fragment A. "or you need to set your activity flags to android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" to keep it from destroyng on screen orientation change" -- that is not a recommended solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had to mention that android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" should be used only when all other attempts have failed.

Comment: Use something like this:   
public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {     
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(MY_ID) == null)
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(MY_ID, new MyFirstFragment()).commit()
}

Comment: Ah, ok! I put this in onCreate()- for my case it's enough:         `if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            showFirstFragment();
        }` and `setRetainInstance(true)` in the super class of my fragments. Now it works as expected. Thanks both of you!