# Is it advisable to manage REST calls in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

If the user e.g. changes device's orientation during the REST (or any other long running async operation), the fragment is detached from the activity.

So if this fragment uses `getActivity()` anywhere in the code handling the REST response, it will raise a null pointer.

I can protect all the calls of `getActivity()` with null checks - but there's still the possibility the activity becomes null between the check-line and the use-line. And also there's lot of places where this is done, so the code will become a mess.

setRetainInstance(true) is not usable if I want to change the layout on orientation change. + There's are also some strange effects with that like: [Multiple fragments, setRetainInstance(true) and screen rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043227/multiple-fragments-setretaininstancetrue-and-screen-rotation)

So this leads me to think maybe its generally bad practice to handle rest calls in fragments?

I have seen some practices where the *activity* contains a non visual fragment to handle the responses. But I can't put this in the fragments, I guess. So I have to use the activity as a mediator and reach the results to the current fragment?

I just thought, it's cleaner to put everything in the fragment. Since I don't need to modify the code elsewhere. And it's then a self contained entity, which I can put somewhere else without problems. But what do I do with these unreliable references to the context? I mean if the fragment is recreated, I really don't care about the detached fragment - it just has to finish whatever it's doing silently and don't disturb my new workflow with exceptions. And of course I don't want to surround everything with `try catch(Exception)` since I care about the exceptions thrown in other situations.

Comment: "setRetainInstance(true) is not usable if I want to change the layout on orientation change" -- yes, it is, as `setRetainInstance(true)` has nothing to do with "change the layout on orientation change". `onCreateView()` is still called on the retained fragment after the configuration change, so it will be able to recreate its UI to take into account the current configuration.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, I didn't know that. Then I will use it, since currently I don't have other reason to recreate the fragment.

Comment: * Still doesn't answer the complete question although, since there can be other reasons that the fragment is detached from the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually use the fragment as the display aspect and the activity as the logic aspect. just like MVC- the fragment is the view and the activity is the controller.

So all my fragments has this code:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (FragmentListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement FragmentListener");
        }
    }
```

and every activity that uses this fragment implement the FragmentListener interface.

Once I got a response from the server I'm just populate (or just calling the right method) the fragment, you can do some null checking here, but It will be rare...

Comment: But as far I understand, some of the advantages of using fragments is that it's supposed to be logic + view. Otherwise you could just use, well, a view. Also if I have only one activity in the app and a lot of fragments all the logic goes to 1 activity and that's messy. And also let's say I want to copy quickly a fragment to other app to add functionality. I will not be able to, without modifying core logic.

Comment: You not *have* to extract logic to activity, you can also use a 3rd class that the activity use it. but I would stay with the logic in the activity. think about tests or the case that you want to fetch things not from the server (for example- fetch info from server async and load this info from file in fragment)

Comment: I am getting data from multiple sources (server and content provider/files) using the fragment. I put the data retrieval logic in a separate class, yes. But the user of this class is the fragment, and not the activity. I also created a fragment superclass to put all common logic. In other words my activity is just a host which handles the frame - action bar, side menu, backbutton, etc. Everything else is in fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can do that. You probably want to look at AsyncTaskLoader and the LoaderManager (they specifically cope with the lifecycle issues you are talking about). Also be aware that task loader IDs have to be unique to the activity, so if you have multiple fragments running loaders hosted within the same activity, the loader id's cant all be the same ;-)

Comment: I'm not using loaders, I'm using a pattern with async service, which helps to get (and process) *always* the response of the server, even when the app is destroyed. But then have this problem delivering to the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

on orientation change, the activity will be re-created. To protect this use the below code

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" in manifest file ( i.e in activity tag )
```

and ovrride the method in your MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need, I needed `setRetainInstance(true)`